# How to merge two msi package into one using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

How to merge two msi package into one using visual studio. So that after installation of one msi other msi would be installed sequentially. I need to bundle 2 msi using Visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i  can think of to is to use custom prerequisites:
•http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7eh4aaa5(v=vs.100).aspx

This way the installer would require that the other two where installed.   Just like you can require that a specific version of .net is installed.

Comment: Is there  any way in visual studio to make bootstrapper project?

Answer (score 1):

Best approach to handle this requirement is to create a `Bootstrapper package` and add second MSI package as a prerequisite for the first installer. First you have to install the bootstrapper manifest generater tool from the link i have provided below. Tool will autogenerate necessary manifest files. You have to copy these files to the following folder(Visual Studio2010) `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages`.

Once thats done go to You `Application deployment project` > `Properties` > `Prerequisite` There you will see your second MSI package as one of the prerequisite option. Just select that and create the MSI. Now when you run the `Setup.exe` created along with your .MSI it will install both MSI in sequence.

- [Creating Bootstrapper Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx)
- [Bootstrapper Msnifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1567)